# writeAll(ResultSet res,Boolean b) method of opencsv adds double quotes around data

Tags: java, opencsv

When I use this function to write to a csv file all the data is embedded in double quotes.

Is there a way to write to csv file without the double quotes?

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(table+".csv"), '\t');
            writer.writeAll(rset, true);
            writer.close();
```

the file contains data in the form

```
"EMPNO" "ENAME" "JOB"   "MGR"   "HIREDATE"  "SAL"   "COMM"  "DEPTNO"    "TAG"   "LOOKUP"
"7369"  "SMITH" "CLERK" "7902"  "17-Dec-1980"   "800"   "2" "20"    "E" "1"
"7499"  "ALLEN" "SALESMAN"  "7698"  "20-Feb-1981"   "1600"  "2" "30"    "E" "2"
"7521"  "WARD"  "SALESMAN"  "7698"  "22-Feb-1981"   "1250"  "2" "30"    "E" "3"
"7566"  "JONES" "MANAGER"   "7839"  "02-Apr-1981"   "2975"  "2" "20"    "E" "2"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(table+".csv"), '\t', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
            writer.writeAll(rset, true);
            writer.close();
```

Reference: [opencsv CSVWriter JavaDoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html)

Comment: what if some values contain tabs?

Comment: You cannot have value containing tabs when your CSV file is separated by tab. Same thing applies for comma or semicolon, or space, or else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to the previous answer (don't have enough points to just add to comments) by @user591593 - while using the NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER constructor, you should escape the values yourself. See [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

More over, it's best to specify a proper encoding, such as UTF-8, instead of assuming that the system default is the correct one:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"), '\t', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

String s = "some fun \t string with \" double quotes and \n new lines";

writer.writeNext(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(s));
```