# Double Quotes getting duplicated while writing CSV file with OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to write a simple `CSVWriter` code using `OpenCSV` library but having a strange issue with it.

> Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       String[] header = {"ONE", "\"TWO\"", "\"THREE\"", "\"FOUR\""};

       CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:/test.csv"), '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

       writer.writeNext(header);

       writer.flush();       
       writer.close();
    }
}
```

> Expected Output:

`ONE|"TWO"|"THREE"|"FOUR"`

> Real Output:

`ONE|""TWO""|""THREE""|""FOUR""`

As we can see there are Double Quotes surrounding TWO, THREE and FOUR but in the output the double quotes are *duplicated*.

I do not want this, have tried several options and constructor of `CSVWriter` class but did not able to sort this out.

Anyone faced similar issue or know a way out?

Thanks

Comment: check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366954/prevent-opencsv-from-writing-quotes-to-csv-file

Comment: done! Thank you for suggestion @RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, the below constructor worked:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:/test.csv"), '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);
```

Reason I see that the `CSVWriter` was considering `"` as a *Escape Character* by default and thus if it comes in String, it was will trying to *Escape* that `"` with `DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER` which is not anything but `"` itself.

By passing `CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER`, the Writer will not worry about checking if there are anything that needed to be in between *Escapes*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsv` builded by `com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder` instead `com.opencsv.CSVWriter`;

you **can't set directly the options as constructor params**, but you have to set it calling the respective methods: `.withQuotechar()` and `.withEscapechar()`

Like this:

```
StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder btcsvBuilder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(myOutputStreamWriter);
StatefulBeanToCsv btcsv = btcsvBuilder.withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER).withEscapechar(CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER).withMappingStrategy(myMapStrategy).withSeparator(',').build();
```